# Ckfinder & Ckeditor in Symfony2 with no bundle

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, ckeditor, ckfinder

I would like to simply use Ckfinder with Ckeditor in Symfony2 without any bundle.

Ckeditor works well already, and Ckfinder is matched with my Ckeditor's textarea. But, when I want to add a picture from the server, I have this error : `"The file browser is disabled for security reasons. Please contact your system administrator and check the CKFinder configuration file."`

I didn't configure at all the Ckfinder, just gave 0777 rights to the ckfinder/userfiles directory.

What I have to do next ?

PS : already looked on the internet, on http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/guide/dev_ckeditor and on http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Installation guides. Easy for normal PHP website, but different for a Symfony2 one.

INFO : I just import the `ckfinder` and the `ckeditor` directories in `/Resources/public/js` directory of my Bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure the CKFinder using [this guide](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-php/configuration.html).
This message is displayed because you have to add some sort of [authentication](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-php/configuration.html#configuration_options_authentication) to you installation.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working, I just set the $config['authentication'] to true. Just one question now, my picture is well uploaded, but, when I try to edit it (rotation) and replace by the existing file, it says "Invalid file.". Thank you

Comment: Hi, could you give some more info? It may be the case that particular image has some problems (ie when rotating the new width is higher then maxHeigth allowed in settings) or some browser problem.